# NVidia CUDA 6.5 Project build error

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

Yesterday I updated my CUDA Toolkit to version 6.5. Since then I can't build any projects except samples provided by NVidia. When I try to build any project I'm getting following error

```
Error   3   error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing     Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_LIB -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\Source.cu.obj "c:\Users\Łukasz\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cu"" exited with code 255.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.targets 593 9   ConsoleApplication1
```

I can build samples provided by nvidia without any errors.

Before 6.5 i was using CUDA 6.0 and compiler was working just fine. I already tried to reinstall toolkit but that didn't help.

[HERE](http://pastebin.com/GYz8h2Ky) is link to detailed output of building process. Maybe that will help solving my issue because I have no clue what I do wrong.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I made some progress. When I switched off (-G) option I'm able to build my code and code from visual studio template given by NVidia.

Problem is that I'd like to have -G switched on.

Comment: Do you use inline PTX in your code?  Also can you give use the smallest amount of code that fails?  Even a simple one that just sets some array values?

Comment: With -G even simplest Hello World program fails and I don't really know what inline PTX is so I most likely don't use it.

Comment: Can you give me your code in the question.  Also the line containing the nvcc command being called to compile.

Comment: At first I tried to compile template that is included in toolkit. It didn't work so I tried to compile code:

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout<<"Test"<<std::endl;
}

That didn't compile either unless I switched off -G option for the compiler. After that everything works fine but I won't be albe to debug device code.

int main()

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  I copied your command from your question and it compiles with and without the -G flag from the command line.

Comment: Before I was using CUDA 6.0 and I could build with or without -G. Problems started after I updated CUDA to 6.5. I have no idea what causes my problems.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to uninstall everything and then re-install.  It could be a bad installation, which I doubt, or you had some of the previous CUDA leftover and could be confusing the compiler.  Sorry I could not be of help. :[

Comment: I already tried to reinstall everything but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the -rdc flag true.

In Visual Studio:

Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Cuda C/C++ -> Common -> Generate Relocatable Device Code: Yes (-rdc=true)